# How do I pass the controller and action parameters to a javascript function in Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

this is what I have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="image_viewer_on(<%= e.id %>, <%= params[:controller] %>); return false;">
```

but I get a 'my_controller_name' is undefined error?

**edit**

I tried:

```
<a href="#" onclick="image_viewer_on(<%= e.id %>, <%= controller_name %>); return false;">

<a href="#" onclick="image_viewer_on(<%= e.id %>, '<%= controller_name %>', 'index'); return false;">
```

with the same result, and

```
<a href="#" onclick="image_viewer_on(<%= e.id %>, <%= controller_name.to_i %>); return false;">
```

which works. Can I parse it somehow, or what do you think?

---

ok so this is how I **fixed it**, I added some quotes around the `<%= controller_name %>`

```
<a href="#" onclick="image_viewer_on(<%= e.id %>, '<%= controller_name %>', 'index'); return false;">
```

Comment: have you tried using the `controller_name` variable? That and `action_name` are built in to every view. Adding this as a comment because I can't see specifically what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca see here a discussion about getting the controller name in the view:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/140912

```
params[:controller]
```

or

```
controller.controller_name
```

You did not specify if yyour error occurs in javascript or ruby. My guess is that is in javascript and it is caused by the fact that you did not enclosed by quotes the controller name and javascript thinks it is a variable with that name.

Comment: please make sure you put the code directly in your StackOverflow answer (since that link could always get pulled down)